# Implement if condition for xpath that does not exist Karate

Tags: karate

I'm working with xml response body and trying to keep my test running even when my xpath does not exist. Here is my feature file

```
When request read("propertyAvail.xml")
And header CWT_DEBUG_LABELS = true
And header CWT_DEBUG_RATES_RANK_LABELS = true
And header Content-Type = "text/xml"
And header CWT_TRAVELER_ID = "A:65887F3"
And header CWT_TRAVELER_ID_TYPE = "portrait"
And method post
Then match response //BookingChannel[2]/RatePlan[1]/TPA_Extensions/InPolicy == "#notnull"
And def inPol = //BookingChannel[2]/RatePlan[1]/TPA_Extensions/InPolicy
And def inPolVal = //BookingChannel[2]/RatePlan[1]/TPA_Extensions/Labels/Label[@Type="CWT_INPOLICY_VALUE"]
And def rateIsInPolicy = Java.type("com.cwt.karate_scripts.CalculationHelper").isInPolicy(inPol, inPolVal)
And match rateIsInPolicy == true
```

Here I want to implement the logic

```
if (//BookingChannel[2]/RatePlan[1]/TPA_Extensions/InPolicy -> does not exist){
  And def inPolVal = 0.0  
  And def rateIsInPolicy = Java.type("com.cwt.karate_scripts.CalculationHelper").isInPolicy(inPol, inPolVal)
  And match rateIsInPolicy == true

else{ 

  And def inPolVal = //BookingChannel[2]/RatePlan[1]/TPA_Extensions/Labels/Label[@Type="CWT_INPOLICY_VALUE"]
  And def rateIsInPolicy = Java.type("com.cwt.karate_scripts.CalculationHelper").isInPolicy(inPol, inPolVal)
  And match rateIsInPolicy == true
```

So I want stay in same feature, same scenario, and keep my test running even if xpath does not exist and do some actions after that. How can I do so? Maybe there is try-catch logic present within karate as well? Please help.

Comment: I just left a comment on previous one, can we consider it as closed?

Comment: I accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `karate.get()` API will gracefully return null if an XPath does not exist. So this works:

```
* def xml1 = <root><one>1</one></root>
* def temp = karate.get('$xml1/root/one')
* def result = temp ? 'yes' : 'no'
* match result == 'yes'

* def xml2 = <root><two>2</two></root>
* def temp = karate.get('$xml2/root/one')
* def result = temp ? 'yes' : 'no'
* match result == 'no'
```

Now just use the techniques in the docs on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic) and you should be able to do what you want. One more thing, there is nothing wrong with calling a second (re-usable) feature file, it can make things simpler in some cases.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for your help and quick response!